# codeigniter arabic keyboard form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my code I provided the form validation like 'alpha'. But when we will use the arabic keyboard, I am getting an error message 'District only contain alphabetic characters'.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I think it is a helpful answer <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581971/how-can-i-make-alpha-dash-work-for-arabic-alphabets">here</a>

Answer (score 0):

I think you may rather modifying in the core libraries of Codeigniter,Or you may use your own custom validations by [Regex in Arabic characters](http://www.google.com.eg/search?hl=ar&sa=X&ei=pn6JToW2JYqI4gT8xaSkDw&ved=0CBUQBSgA&q=regex%20in%20arabic%20characters&spell=1&biw=1440&bih=742)

And if you can please provide a code sample it may helps