# How can I make alpha_dash work for Arabic alphabets?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I want to add rule for Arabic fields to ensure that it contains only characters or number.

`alpha_dash`  only works with English alphabets, how can I make it support Arabic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha dash is not a standard php function.

This is the function you referred to however

```
function alpha_dash($str)
{
   return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9_-])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

This should match arabic letters, numbers, underscores and the minus sign.

```
function alpha_dash($str)
{
   return ( ! preg_match("/^[\-_ \d\p{Arabic}]*\p{Arabic}[\d\p{Arabic}]*$/ui", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

edit: I might have messed up the regex, but now at least you have something to go on.

Comment: This is very good way, but please edit the regex and add the space charachter

Comment: The space character is now added. Just keep in mind that I can give no guarantees that it works or is accurate. Hopefully someone can verify this.

Comment: I will make heavy testing also.