# Codeigniter alpha and alpha_numeric function to support Arabic language for validation

Tags: regex, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am very very very bad in regex and unfortunately this is one time I really hope I knew it. I have the following function outlining the embedding of arabic support in the regex expression:

```
function alpha_dash($str)
{
   return ( ! preg_match("/^[\-_ \d\p{Arabic}]*\p{Arabic}[\d\p{Arabic}]*$/ui", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Now this is coped from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581971/how-can-i-make-alpha-dash-work-for-arabic-alphabets). I want the same support for Alpha and Alpha numeric functions. I really can't play around with regex because I always break things down when I do.

Hope someone could really help :)

EDIT:

```
public function alpha($str)
    {
        return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }


public function alpha_numeric($str)
    {
        return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }
```

I need these two functions to support the arabic language

Comment: What do you want to do? Example input. Desired result. Also you can try using single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: I update the question with functions I need to support the arabic :)

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ is a nice resource for checking your regexp's

Comment: The function you posted does check for the alpha-numeric, \d <-- to match numbers

Comment: @ahmad [0-9] does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the [doc I found on the PHP website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) about regex, this should work :

```
public function alpha($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match('/^([a-z]|\p{Arabic})+$/iu', $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
} 

public function alpha_numeric($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]|\p{Arabic})+$/iu', $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Using this, it should match alpha+arabic or alphanum + arabic. Give it a try. I think it might need that PCRE to be compiled with the `--enable-unicode-properties` switch however, which I'm not sure to check this.

Answer (score 1):

i have this code in MY_Form_validation Library works fine

```
   public function alpha_ar($str) {
    $str = (strtolower($this->CI->config->item('charset')) != 'utf-8') ? utf8_encode($str) : $str;
    return (!preg_match("/^([إد ج ح خ ه ع غ ف ق ث ص ض ط ك م ن ت ا أ ل ب ي س ش ظ ز و ة ى لا ر ؤ ء ئ ذ])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```